# Adding/Editing Entries under a Field from Different Tables Using a Single Form in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to create a form that allows you to add new or edit existing fields from multiple tables that are connected. For example, the attached image shows the relationships of the tables. I want to create a form where you can add a new entry under `MACHNAME`and have it displayed in all the tables that contain the field `MACHNAME` (`A_SETUP`, `A_MCHCONFG`, `A_CHCONFIG`, and `A_MCHMASTR`). How do I do it?

[Table Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQkni.jpg)

Comment: Although it might seem like a simple, straightforward question, this really is too broad since there are multiple ways of handling this.  You've also not shared enough info to really know which technique might be preferred.  For instance, you could use sub-forms linked via a primary and foreign key.  But if you want records automatically added in multiple tables when a key record is created in a main table, you'll need to add Data Macros or VBA code to Form events. Rather than making it implicit, you might find adding a button useful in controlling when this behavior happens.

Comment: @CPerkins Thanks for the feedback. The truth is that I have no preference over what method to use. I was first trying to use subforms like you mentioned, but I was having trouble making it work. VBA code would also work, I just don't know how to do it. What would you personally do in this case?